# How to embed iframe(s) inside of frameset?

Tags: html, iframe, frameset

My browser extension "opens" but does not display on webpages with `frameset`.

Example: Go to this example: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols And replace the code with the following:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</frameset>
```

Notice the iframe does not show up. However, if you change the `frameset` tag to `div` tag then the iframe will display.

Answer (score 0):

The `frameset` tag can only hold `frame` elements, not `iframes`. To use `iframe`s, you can create a similar layout using `div` tags and CSS.

Note: `frameset` is not supported in HTML5 and should not be used.

Comment: In this case I don't have control over the page since it's hosted by someone else. I've built an extension using `iframe`, which is embedded on their page.